# Cannot use list of classes by base interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq, polymorphism

My interface IDerived is inherited from IBase:

```
public IDerived : IBase { ... }
```

I have method which needs IList:

```
public MyClass
{
    public static void DoSmth(IList<IBase> bases)
    { ... }
}
```

But attempt to pass list of derived objects:

```
IList<IDerived> derivedObjs = ...;
MyClass.DoSmth(derivedObjs);
```

causes error:

```
Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<IDerived> is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<IBase>'
```

I can implement something 'stupid' like that:

```
MyClass.DoSmth(derivedObjs.Select(d=>d as IBase).ToList());
```

But that sounds... unprofessional.

I remember few years ago I was fighting with similar problem and that should be resolved somehow by allowing either 'DoSmth' or 'MyClass' to convert objects to base class... but cannot find any solution.

Please advise, what is the proper way to pass list of derived objects to the method which expects list of objects pointed by base class.

Thanks

Comment: Look at generic covariance and contravariance to see how to work with generic interfaces with type inheritance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: _"what is the proper way to pass list of derived objects to the method which expects list of objects pointed by base class"_ -- you can't. If the compiler allowed you to, then the method you called could add an item different from the type allowed in the list, since it's allowed to add any base class item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TSomething<TDerived>` is only assignable to `TSomething<TBase>` (where `TDerived` is derived from `TBase`), if `TSomething` is [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) with respect to its type parameter.

One of the preconditions for a type to be logically covariant is that it only ever returns instances of its type parameter, and never has to accept them. This is the case with read only iterables like `IEnumerable<T>`, but is **not** the case with `IList<T>`, which must accept references of the type of its type parameter in methods such as `Add`.

Consider, for example, the following situation:

```
class Base: IBase { }
class Derived: IDerived { }
...
MyClass.DoSmth(new List<IDerived>());
...
public static void DoSmth(IList<IBase> bases)
{
    bases.Add(new Base());
}
```

If the compiler allowed you to do this, you'd have gone and broken type safety, since a `Base` is not an `IDerived`.

The fix here depends on what you're doing in `DoSmth`. If you're only iterating over `bases`, you should accept an iterable interface that actually *is* covariant, i.e. `IEnumerable<IBase>`:

```
public static void DoSmth(IEnumerable<IBase> bases) { ... }
```

If you actually do need the operations supported by the `IList` interface, there is nothing for it but to either change your existing `derivedObjs` to be a `IList<IBase>`, or to create a new list by using `Cast` and `ToList`:

```
MyClass.DoSmth(derivedObjs.Cast<IBase>().ToList());
```

Comment: So that is not about my family of interfaces, that is about their container, which is IList in this case. Thanks.